# SQL query and dataframes using Spark/java

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, geosparql, geospark

I am a beginner in spark and I got stuck in how to make a sql request using dataframe.

I have the two followings dataframe.

```
dataframe_1
+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|id               |geometry_tyme    |geometry              |rayon                |
+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|50               |Polygon          |[00 00 00 00 01 0...] |200                  |
|54               |Point            |[00 00 00 00 01 0.. ] |320179               |
+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------------+
dataframe_2
+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
|id2              |long             |lat                   |               
+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
|[70,50,600,]     | -9.6198783      |44.5942549            |
|[20,140,39,]     |-6.6198783       |44.5942549            |
+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

I want to execute the following request.

```
"SELECT dataframe_1.* FROM dataframe_1 WHERE dataframe_1.id IN ("
                            + id2
                            + ") AND ((dataframe_1.geometry_tyme='Polygon' AND (ST_WITHIN(ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',"
                            + long
                            + ",' ',"
                            + lat
                            + ",')'),4326),dataframe_1.geometry))) OR ( (dataframe_1.geometry_tyme='LineString' OR dataframe_1.geomType='Point') AND     ST_Intersects(ST_buffer(dataframe_1.geom,(dataframe_1.rayon/100000)),ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',"
                            + long
                            + ",' ',"
                            + lat
                            + ",')'),4326)))) "
```

I'm really stuck, should I join the two data frames or what?
I tried to join the two dataframes with id and idZone like this :

```
     dataframe_2.select(explode(col("id2").as ("id2"))).join(dataframe_1,col("id2").equalTo(dataframe_1.col("id")));
```

but it seems to me that making a join is not the right choice.

I need you help .

Thank you

Comment: why are you "stuck"? Just run the SQL query itself and you're done

Comment: thank you for your reply , The query is in sql , I want to execute the same query using the columns of the two dataframes on spark using java langage.

Comment: I know that the query is SQL, but I do not get why you can't run the query itself? You can even call `explode` inside the SQL query. Anyways, why can't you do explode on the second dataframe and then do the join on the ID columns? What does not work here?

Answer (score 1):

1.create temp views from your dataframes.

```
dataframe_1.createOrReplaceTempView("dataframe_1")
dataframe_2.createOrReplaceTempViews("dataframe_2")
```

2.Run your SQL as `final_df = spark.sql("your SQL here")`